# How to change language using command line on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, locale, language

I use the following command line to set my system in English (installed in French) :

```
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
```

However, when I boot into graphical mode, the desktop menu, directories names etc. are still in French.

The only way I can set everything in english is to use the graphical gnome menu "Applications > System tools > Settings > Region and Language".

Is there a way to change system language using command line as if I used the graphical menu?

EDIT :

In fact, my problem was coming from the fact that I was modifying through SSH with user root the system language but then loging through graphical console (workstation VM) under a standard user who has its language already defined. localectl works well but to define default language for a specific user, I must define $LANG in my .bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the system language from the terminal , use the following line :

```
sudo system-config-language --text
```

Select your prefered language then validate.

Changes will take effect after the next reboot.

The `--text` option to avoid the prompt of the GUI.

Comment: I edited my question because I found out why I could'nt get the result I wanted. Your answer helped me a lot finding out why it couldn't work and also I didn't know system-config-language. I had to install it with yum by the way.

Comment: CentOS 8: `sudo: system-config-language: command not found`

Comment: yum install -y system-config-language

Comment: Error: unable to find a match: system-config-language